# How to check if connection is lost in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

When connection to the server is lost during RPC call an InvocationException is passed to the AsyncCallback#onFailure(...).

But InvocationException is also passed if there is e.g. a NullPointerException on the server.

How could I distinguish between these two cases? How do I know that it is a connection problem, not just some RuntimeException on the server?

Answer (score 4):

You should be given a `StatusCodeException` for any network-related error. If the browser can't connect to the server, or the connection was aborted, it'll have a status code of 0.